# Change the owner of an offline database without bringing it online

Tags: sql-server

If it is possible I would like to know how to do it via Sql Server Management Studio.

When a database is online I can do it in the files option of the db properties. I don't see that option when the database is offline.

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Whats the reason behind to change the option of an offline database ? You cant do it

Comment: I don't know the reason for it too,but if you want to change it without giving access to the database, so: 1. Set the database to online in a single user mode. 2. Change the owner 3.Set database back to offline .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can't be done without bringing the database online, and this is not just a GUI problem.

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::test TO sa;
```

Yields:

> Msg 942, Level 14, State 4, Line 1
>   
> Database 'test' cannot be opened because it is offline.

So, as one of the comments suggested, bring it online, set it to single_user if you need to, change the owner, then take it back offline.

```
ALTER DATABASE test SET ONLINE;
ALTER DATABASE test SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::test TO sa;
ALTER DATABASE test SET MULTI_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
ALTER DATABASE test SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
```

Though I have to wonder, why do you care who the owner is until you've brought the database online?